# ¿Cómo hacer fetch a un documento JS?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Estoy intentando hacer un `fetch` a un documento `js`, así como normalmente hago `fetch` a los documentos `json` y puedo replicar su contenido, he intentado leer el archivo `js` con el `fetch`.

Hasta aquí bien, lo malo es que no obtengo el resultado que me esperaba:

```js
fetch('js/modulos/ultimate-001.js')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Creía que podría visualizar el contenido de dicho `js` mediante el `fetch`, pero no es así.

¿Se puede hacer? ¿En qué estaría fallando?

Comment: ¿Fetch a un archivo `.js`? ¿Acaso no es mejor ponerlo en contexto directamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No te funciona porque intentas procesarlo como un documento JSON:

```
fetch('js/modulos/ultimate-001.js') // pide el fichero
  .then(response => response.json())// toma la respuesta e intenta un JSON.parse(...)
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Si quieres tratarlo como "texto", usa text() en lugar de json()

```
fetch('js/modulos/ultimate-001.js')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Un ejemplo sencillo:

```js
fetch('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js')
.then(data => data.text())
.then(data => document.querySelector('code').innerText=data)
```

```css
code {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<code>
</code>
```

Comment: Siendo un archivo `.js` ¿no es mejor ponerlo en contexto directamente? ¿Qué justificaría hacer `fetch` en este caso?

Comment: Carga dinámica de código, mostrar en un editor online el fichero... No es habitual pero puede tener sentido. Por ejemplo si el servidor lo devuelve con el content-type "text/plain", lo que hará que el navegador por defecto deniegue su ejecución

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Brutal como siempre, muchísimas gracias